# Including rails_admin configuration as a mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm not sure why this is not working for me, but I would like to have the configuration of each model that is under the scope of rails_admin to be a mixin that I include into a model.  This gives me the benefit of a separation of concern, while avoiding having to restart the server each time I make a change which would be an issue with just using the rails_admin.rb file.

So I have a model, app/models/section.rb

```
class Section
  include SectionAdmin
```

And in models/section_admin.rb (I put it here to get it working before moving it into lib) I have:

```
module SectionAdmin
  rails_admin do 
    ...
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined method `rails_admin' for main:Object
```

Which is confusing to me, since as a mixin I thought it wasn't evaluated until it was included.  It's also confusing because even when I include 'require "rails_admin"' in the module I still get the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Show your routes.  Did you restart the webserver after migration?

Comment: I didn't have a migration to run since I was just moving code around.  i also didn't make any changes to routes since this is just an include of a mixin, nothing has changed in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in rails 4.0.0

```
# models/admin/user.rb
module Admin
  module User

    ::User.rails_admin do 

      list do
        field :name
        field :email
      end    

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be the cleanest method to handle this in Rails 4

My Concern:

```
# models/concerns/rails_admin_posts.rb
module RailsAdminPosts
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

My Model:

```
# models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RailsAdminPosts

  ...

end
```